# ¿Cómo eliminar unas determinadas palabras de un string?

Tags: javascript

***Dibujando un texto en canvas:***

```
var text = prompt('QUE QUIERES DIBUJAR?','');
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "30px Arial";
ctx.fillText(text,10,50);
```

Como puedo hacer, que si el usuario ***ingresa una texto*** y entre eso tiene ***cierta palabra que NO quiero*** que se dibuje, como se hace?

Ejemplo:

*Siempre que un usuario ingresa la palabra* **"GAY"** dentro de un texto como: "ERNESTO ERES MUY GAY"

no se dibuje esa palabra, pero el resto SI SE DIBUJE, osea se dibujaria solamente:

***ERNESTO ERES MUY***

entonces hacer como UN **ARRAY DE PALABRAS PROHIBIDAS**

***Mi intento:***

```js
var prohibidas = ["ar","cl"];
var b = prohibidas.join('');
var text = prompt('QUE QUIERES DIBUJAR?','');
document.write(b);
if (text.indexOf(b) != -1) {

alert("NO SE DIBUJA");

}
else {
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "30px Arial";
ctx.fillText(text,10,50);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es ir buscando si cada una de las palabras está dentro del texto que acaban de introducir y si es así, reemplazarlo por vacío `""`.

Ejemplo:

```js
var palabrasProhibidas = ['feo','tonto','palabra-vulgar-1','palabra-vulgar-2'];
var numeroPalabrasProhibidas = palabrasProhibidas.length;

var text = prompt('QUE QUIERES DIBUJAR?','');

while(numeroPalabrasProhibidas--) {
   if (text.indexOf(palabrasProhibidas[numeroPalabrasProhibidas])!=-1) {
       text = text.replace(new RegExp(palabrasProhibidas[numeroPalabrasProhibidas], 'ig'), "");
   }
}

var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "30px Arial";
ctx.fillText(text,10,50);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Si en el ejemplo anterior introducimos:

> Este ejercicio es un palabra-vulgar-2 y mi palabra-vulgar-2 huele a palabra-vulgar-1

Nos devolvería lo siguiente:

> Este ejercicio es un y mi huele a

**ACLARACIÓN:** La Regex la utilizo para que detecte todas las palabras (`g`) sin considerar mayúsculas y minúsculas (`i`). Si se quiere que detecte entre minúsculas y mayúsculas habría que quitar la `i` de la regex.

Comment: Gracias, pero porque le pones --?

Comment: ya entendi :) gracias

Comment: @EduardoSebastian Es para que recorra el array con el bucle tomando en cuenta su longitud.

Comment: @FranciscoRomero Habría que tener en cuenta mayúsculas y minúsculas  quizá

Comment: @Dev.Joel Ya está modificado para que no tenga en cuenta mayúsculas y minúsculas.

Comment: cuando esta en corchetes

Comment: Si ,pero no elimina los corchetes a eso me refiero, como lo hago¡

Comment: imagina la palabra prohibida contiene corchetes, no me los elimina

Comment: @EduardoSebastian Claro, ahora la Regex solo está preparada para que te quite la palabra en cuestión, no lo que le rodea. Habría que cambiar la Regex para todas las variantes aunque creo que eso sería para una nueva pregunta, porque también tendrías que detectar paréntesis, guiones, etc... lo cual creo que no es el objetivo de esta pregunta.

Comment: No creo sano repetir palabras por llamarlas de algún modo "controversiales", ni siquiera con el "pretexto" de que estas están en la pregunta. ¿Qué diferencia hay en cuanto a lo técnico de la solución si se usa las palabras de la pregunta u otras "no controversiales". Lo menciono porque el sitio sería mejor si mantenemos las respuestas aptas "para toda la familia" :)

Comment: @Rubén Tienes razón. Simplemente puse unas que no eran demasiado "fuertes" para que se viera más claramente que las eliminaba pero eres libre de poner otras si lo deseas. Siento las molestias.